# How to create interaction between two android applications

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I have 2 applications with their source codes. When I press button in application one, I need to background "press" button in application 2 (start specific action from it, not MainActivity). So, for example, do command like

```
send "press_button2" -> APP2
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: try event driven and have both applications listen to events on the bus

Comment: The best way is probably to find another method to achieve whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: @Stultuske do you mean by using eventBus library by greenrobot?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi I'm not familiar with that library. but event driven requires an eventbus that the services listen to to filter the events applicable to them

Comment: @Stultuske can the eventbus be shared between two different applications in event driven? In EventBus library that's not possible

Comment: consider the bus as a seperate instance. a sort of thread running in the background, that all services listen to

Comment: @Stultuske I see, which would it be the context of the thread you're talking about?

Comment: I have ...no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite a generic question but you'll have to use an implicit intent from your "APP1" and read the intent action in your "APP2".
The steps will be:

1. Define the implicit intent in your APP1, something like

```kotlin
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "press_button2")
    type = "text/plain"
}
startActivity(sendIntent)
```

2. In your APP2, set up your manifest to receive the specified action in an activity of your choice, using an intent filter:

```xml
<activity android:name="ClickActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

3. In your "APP2" handle the incoming intent in your activity, something like:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        when {
            intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND -> {
                if ("text/plain" == intent.type) {
                    intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)?.let {
                        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
                        if (it == "press_button2"){
                            myButton.performClick()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Be aware that also other apps would be able to manage your "send text action", so android will show an app chooser to the user, you'll not be able to switch between the two apps seamlessly.

Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send)

Comment: this is quite vague as an answer. probably better suited as a comment

Comment: Thanks a lot! Best!